# Tracking payment is done within 10 minutes

Tags: java, servlets, paypal

i want to do develop a appointment payment system.
After booking appointment If payment is not made before 10 minutes means i have cancel that appointment.

```
I am using ebs payment system.
```

After appointment booking it will go ebs website.
How can i track payment can be done with in 10 minutes. 
Shall i need to create thread for this, if required result not came means i have to cancel that appointment?

```
How can i do this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used EBS and couldn't find an API specification online. However, the general scheme is that the service will redirect the user to some *pingback* URL after a successful transaction. This pingback URL contains the transaction ID, and so you need nothing more than a simple servlet that checks against the EBS services that the transaction with the given ID was truly successful. After the check, you can send a message to the user in the HTML response and trigger the needed actions in your system.

Regarding the cancelation part, you can schedule a cron job (for example with Quartz scheduler) that periodically checks unpaid appointments and trashes the ones too old. However I think 10 minutes are a very short period because the payment itself may last more than 10 minutes.

A better approach is giving the user 10 minutes to *finalize* the order. A finalized order can still be paid, unpaid or even canceled, but won't be trashed by the periodic job.

Comment: yes this i did.runs properly.If payment is not done(user closed browser)or response only not came how can i track for 10 minutes?

Comment: You may schedule a cron job that runs every X minutes and trashes unpaid appointments. **NOTE** 10 minutes seems too a little time. And what happens if the user stays on the EBS sites for 15 minutes before finalizing the payment? And what happens if the payment itself takes more than 10 minutes to complete? I guess users won't be very happy, and you'll have to give back a lot of money

Comment: Ok thanks.I will go through cron job. But here you are talking about a sheduler that repeatedly checks all appointments for a time interval whether it is paid or not.unpaid appointments are canceled for that time interval.But i want for particular one appointment,I have to track  whether its paid or not within 10 minutes.(not all appointments).Through cron job i can do it o what?

Comment: All appointments are stored in just one table. In your example, every 10 minutes a piece of code is executed that will trash unpaid appointment older than a threshold. Assuming this piece of code executes in no time and is started in the very moment it's supposed to, you'll have that an appointment can stay unpaid in your system for a period between 10 and almost 20 minutes. If you schedule a job per-task you'll likely need more system resources